# What is the most logical way to export React components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

When writing React components in ES6, I sometimes wonder what the most logical way would be to export a component. I have found three ways to do so, and I mostly employ the first one:

#### export default class

```
export default class extends Component {
    render() {
        //
    }
}
```

Seems to the most straightforward way. The only downside I can see is that the component is not explicitly named in the file except for the filename.

#### export default class ComponentName

```
export default class ComponentName extends Component {
    render() {
        //
    }
}
```

Seems to be practically the same as above, apart from the class being named explicitly. 
*Side question: Is there a difference between the two above when importing the component?*

#### class with separate export

```
class ComponentName extends Component {
    render() {
        //
    }
}

export default ComponentName
```

I think this also is programmatically identical to the other two examples, but I'm unsure.

Does employing one of these three examples have a notable benefit over the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> export default class

```
export default class extends Component { ... }
```

***Problems with this:***

- You won't be able to refer to the class from within the class - so won't be able to access its static properties
- You also won't be able to define static properties on this class from outside of it which is often what you want to do with `defaultProps` and `propTypes`
- In case something within the class errors it will be harder to debug because the class is unnamed so it won't show up in the stack traces

---

> export default class ComponentName

```
export default class ComponentName extends Component { ... }
```

*( Benefits of this: You avoid all of the above problems and it's short and concise. )*

***Problems with this:***

- If you want to wrap your component in a Higher Order Function such as with Redux's connect it can make the class signature really long making it hard to read

---

> class with separate export

```
class ComponentName extends Component { ... }

export default ComponentName
```

***Benefits of this:***

- You avoid all of the above problems

Answer (score 2):

You should pick the third option since it's cleaner to wrap your component.
Example:

```
class ComponentName extends Component {
    render() {
        //
    }
}

export default connect(null)(ComponentName);
```

Answer (score 1):

I use class with separate exports because it feels cleaner to me especially when you need to wrap your component with the likes of redux connect, material-ui styles and many libraries out there.

Answer (score 0):

These export methods do pretty much the same thing all around. I personally think it comes down to consistency (you want to use the same method throughout your app) and I prefer using component names as I can then use things like `instanceOf`

Also if I am using redux I prefer the last method (separate export statement) to use connect.